# Enable CORS on a .NET Core Api?

Tags: .net-core, cors

I am trying to allow my ANgular app running at `localhost:4200` to be able to request data from my back end api .NET Core 2.2 api running at `localhost:44337`.  I have added a Cores policy in `ConfigureServices`, added it to `Configure`, and added a `UseCors` annotation on my endpoints, but I still get this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44337/api/users/1' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Startup.cs

```
public string DefaultCorsPolicy = "DefaultCorsPolicy";

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(DefaultCorsPolicy,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200/");
                });
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors(DefaultCorsPolicy);
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

UsersController.cs

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[EnableCors("DefaultCorsPolicy")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetUser(int id)
{
    var settings = await _service.GetUser(id);
    return Ok(settings);
}
```

If I add `Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")` in the actual `GetUser` method, it will work.  But I don't want to brute force it.

I made sure to place both `AddCors` and `UseCors` calls at the beginning of `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` respectively.  But it still will not work.

Comment: Your configuration appears correct. In what way is it "not working"? Here is the MS documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: When the angular app calls the `users` endpoint, I would expect to receive use data - instead, I get the error above in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what works in my case (same what you have described).
If this works you can start narrowing.

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(DefaultCorsPolicy,
        builder => builder
            .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials());
});
```

of course i have no `[EnableCors("DefaultCorsPolicy")]` Attribute as i am allowing it on all methods `.AllowAnyMethod()`.

Comment: Yes, that worked!  It looks like MS changed the syntax for AddCors for 2.2.  Go figure.  Thanks!